# Is this a bug in Excel formula evaluation? If not please explain expression evaluation

Tags: excel-formula

Insert values in cells as follows: `A1:2, B1:0, C1:1`
and in cell D1 the formula: `=IF(A1>1*AND(B1>0)*AND(C1=0),0,1)` --> `0` (incorrect (?) result)

Excel from Office Professional Plus 2021 Version 2205

I do not claim that this is a good formula; it is from a question asked of me, where the intention was `=IF(AND(A1>1,B1>0,C1=0),0,1)` or more simply `=--(NOT(AND(A1>1,B1>0,C1=0)))`

Yet it is valid in terms of Excel formula syntax and gives - in terms of my understanding of the syntax - an incorrect result

Here are some things I've tried

1. `=A1>1`, `=B1>0`, `=C1=0` --> `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `FALSE` respectively
2. `=A1>1`, `=AND(B1>0)`, `=AND(C1=0)` --> `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `FALSE`
3. `=TRUE*FALSE*FALSE` --> `0`
4. `=IF(TRUE*FALSE*FALSE,0,1)` --> `1`

all as expected

Fiddling with cell values suggests (I can't claim to have tested comprehensively) that

- values in `B1` and `C1` do not matter
- the result "flips" (from 0 to 1) when setting `A1` to any numeric value `<= 0`
  (even more confusing because the result of evaluating `A1>1` should flip at `1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple.
You are getting the result for `=IF(A1>(1*AND(B1>0)*AND(C1=0)),0,1)` but it seems like you want the result for `=IF((A1>1)*AND(B1>0)*AND(C1=0),0,1)`.

Set your brackets accordingly and read up on [Calculation operators and precedence in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/calculation-operators-and-precedence-in-excel-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a)

Comment: Nice (and obvious).  Thanks. Couldn't see the wood for the trees ;-)